# Aptoide has update for Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, aptoide

Installed Aptoide and noticed that it had some updates on some of the independently installed apps and updated it. But I noticed it had an update for the Google Play store, yet the Google Play Store program hasn't got an update in its own store?

How can that happen?

I assume Google has a longer approval process for apps so some apps in Aptoide will have updates sooner, like SuperSU, but Google's own app store app? Sounds odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can that happen? Some Android user in the world receives the Store update in its rooted device, then get the apk and uploads it to Aptoide.

Google Play Store updates automatically. Some devices get the update faster than others but it's entirely not recommended update manually the Play Store.

There are a lot of bad guys out there...

Just wait. Sooner or later the update will come because Google doesn't like older versions of their own apps.